# Understanding "baseUrl" and "paths" in TypeScript with * glob

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, tsconfig-paths

I have a monorepo created with yarn workspaces and the following folder structure:

```
├── foo                   (workspace @project/foo)
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── index.ts
├── bar                   (workspace @project/bar)
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── index.ts
├── package.json          (monorepo root)
└── tsconfig.json         (base tsconfig)
```

And the following settings in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "@project/foo/*": "./packages/foo/src/*",
      "@project/bar/*": "./packages/bar/src/*"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

In the `@project/bar` workspace, I want to import modules from `@project/foo`:

```
import foo from "@project/foo";
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot find module '@project/foo' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

If I remove the `*` symbols from both the keys and the values of the "paths" object, the code compiles. Why is that? How can I keep the `*` glob pattern and make non-relative imports to my local modules?

Comment: Isn't it that @project/foo/*": "./packages/foo/src/*", is mapping to ./packages... and that doesn't exist? I think it would be mapping relative to baseUrl i.e. "./foo/* to keep the  glob (untested).

Answer (score 0):

roots should be defined separately because `/` blocks `@project/foo` from import, only `@project/foo/` and `@project/foo/something` are allowed.

```
"@project/foo": "./packages/foo/src",
"@project/bar": "./packages/foo/bar",
"@project/foo/*": "./packages/foo/src/*",
"@project/bar/*": "./packages/bar/src/*"
```

---

In case of monorepo you can't use `/*` because after compilation it won't be accessible in the same way as at runtime in monorepo.

The right way is to point to public_api of the projects

```
"@project/foo": "./packages/foo/src/public_api",
"@project/bar": "./packages/foo/bar/public_api",
```

The same for subprojects:

```
"@project/foo/sub": "./packages/foo/src/sub/public_api",
```

Comment: What's the difference between paths and roots?

Comment: `roots` (correct is `rootDirs`) are directories where you have projects / modules / components whereas `paths` are aliases to projects / modules / components in these roots and they are used to resolve imports.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I don't think this answer my question. I'm particularly interested in non-relative imports of local modules, e.g. like in monorepos, whereas `rootDirs` is ostensibly aimed at relatively importing files that will be clustered together at build time.

Comment: You can't use relative imports between projects in a monorepo, it has to be always `projectName` or `projectName/subProjects`. As I understand your question the issue is that `@project/foo` doesn't work. for that you need to add `@project/foo` to the `paths` of the monorepo beside `@project/foo/*`.